# PCL Error Reading PLY

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am not able to read PLY files with PCL and have tried various inputs even the Stanford bunny. The error I get is

```
parse error: couldn't read the magic string
[pcl::PLYReader::read] problem parsing header!
[pcl::PLYReader::read] problem parsing header!
Couldn't read ply file
```

Looking here https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/ply/ply_parser.cpp it's trying to read 4 characters which matches with the file contents

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 3511
property double x
property double y
property double z
element face 0
property list int int vertex_indices
end_header
```

**Edit**

The code

```
if (pcl::io::loadPLYFile(filename, out_pcd) == -1) {
    PCL_ERROR("Couldn't read ply file \n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have opened the file successfully in meshlab so I don't think the file is badly formatted.

**Edit 2**

My C++ isn't great and I wasn't sure how to debug deep into PCL so instead copied their code into my `main()`. It runs fine and can parse the *magic string* without triggering the above error (`!istream`).

```
// PCL SRC START
std::ifstream istream (pathToInput, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

std::string line;
int line_number_ = 0;

char line_delim = '\n';
int char_ignore_count = 0;

// magic
char magic[4];
istream.read (magic, 4);

// Check if CR/LF, setup delim and char skip
if (magic[3] == '\r')
{
    istream.ignore (1);
    line_delim = '\r';
    char_ignore_count = 1;
}

++line_number_;
if (!istream)
{
  if (error_callback_)
    error_callback_ (line_number_, "parse error: couldn't read the magic string");
  return false;
}
// PCL SRC END

// VALUE OF magic IS 'ply\r'
```

Comment: As usual the error is in the code you didn't post. Using my crystal ball the most likely explanation is that your code is giving the wrong file location to the parser. You could test this theory by trying to open the files your self using the same code that the parser does and see if that succeeds.

Comment: What is the value of `filename`? That is the crucial question.

Comment: I just used a breakpoint to grab the value of `filename` and did a `cat` in terminal and it prints the contents of the ply as above.

Comment: Doing a cat is not a valid test, because you are testing the filename in a different environment from your program. In particular the current working directory could make a difference.

Comment: But it's a bit of a mystery. The file content is correct, the filename is (apparently) correct. The code inside the library fails, but the same code outside the library works. The only explanation I can think of is that something changes between your main and your library call. What that is is hard to say.

Comment: You really should up your C++ skills and debug into the library.